# Ignoring Duplicate Records But Bumping Them Up Top

Tags: php, mysql, sql, duplicates, feed

I am making a feed system similar to the way facebook works now what I am trying to implement is the duplicate functionality.

if a user writes the same post= then don't display it duplicatly as PHP normally does by default but bump it up the top so users knows another user as re-wrote it

Here's my query

```
$select_posts_from_groups_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM spud_groups_posts LEFT JOIN spud_groups_members
 ON spud_groups_posts.group_url = spud_groups_members.gurl WHERE member_name='$mybb_username' GROUP BY post_body ORDER BY time_posted DESC" );
```

how can I get it to bump it self as the latest update once a user re duplicates it it would let users know that some one else has shared it

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three solutions

Assuming you have a update timing field on your data record called `time_updated`, there are a couple of things you could do:

1. you could simply max the two:

> `ORDER BY max(time_posted,time_updated) DESC`

This might give issues with `NULL` values though

---

2. substitute `NULL`s in the `time_updated`

> `ORDER BY nvl(time_updated, time_posted) DESC`

(Oracle sql syntax `nvl()` substitutes `NULL` in the 1st param with the 2nd param - don't know what DB you are using)

---

3. always store `time_updated` (the best solution IMO). When creating the post (initially) set `time_updated = time_created` AND use

> `ORDER BY time_updated DESC`

Comment: I didn't need to use a time_updated table I just followed your method but only with the time_posted table and thanks loads :D

Comment: also now how would I only allow it to bump if the orginal/first post that identical to the rest is less then 3 days old?
thanks ;)